# extracting/copying audio from a specific part of a video file, possible?

Tags: debian, audio, ffmpeg

Let's say I have a 2 hour movie and I want to extract/copy audio in another file say 5 minutes between 01:25:00 and 01:30:00, is there a way to do that.

The file is in .avi format -

```
Format                                   : AVI
Format/Info                              : Audio Video Interleave
File size                                : 929 MiB
Duration                                 : 2h 44mn
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 790 Kbps
Writing application                      : VirtualDubMod 1.5.4.1 (build 2178/release)
Writing library                          : VirtualDubMod build 2178/release

Video
ID                                       : 0
Format                                   : MPEG-4 Visual
Format profile                           : Advanced Simple@L5
Format settings, BVOP                    : 1
Format settings, QPel                    : No
Format settings, GMC                     : No warppoints
Format settings, Matrix                  : Custom
Codec ID                                 : XVID
Codec ID/Hint                            : XviD
Duration                                 : 2h 44mn
Bit rate                                 : 662 Kbps
Width                                    : 672 pixels
Height                                   : 288 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 2.35:1
Frame rate                               : 23.976 (23976/1000) fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.143
Stream size                              : 778 MiB (84%)
Writing library                          : XviD 1.2.1 (UTC 2008-12-04)

Audio
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 1
Format profile                           : Layer 3
Mode                                     : Joint stereo
Mode extension                           : MS Stereo
Codec ID                                 : 55
Codec ID/Hint                            : MP3
Duration                                 : 2h 44mn
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 115 Kbps
Nominal bit rate                         : 128 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 136 MiB (15%)
Alignment                                : Aligned on interleaves
Interleave, duration                     : 24 ms (0.58 video frame)
Interleave, preload duration             : 485 ms
Writing library                          : LAME3.98r
Encoding settings                        : -m j -V 4 -q 2 -lowpass 17 --abr 128
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `ffmpeg`? Something like

```
ffmpeg -vn \      # no video
  -ss 01:25:00 \  # start offset
  -t 300 \        # duration
  -i foo.avi bar.mp3
```

might do the trick.

Comment: tried worked. Just a query, what needs to be done if I want video to be also saved ?

Comment: Probably by nixing the no video option and instead specifying an output filename that `ffmpeg` thinks is a video.

Comment: Was able to have different media containers, ffmpeg is cool.